# Azure Deployment Failed when trying to create a storage account

Tags: azure

Following these steps https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/

once I click 'Create' I get the error "Deployment failed" here are the full details;

```
OPERATION IDE03BAC94EFAA1295
TRACKING ID5c3b3e63-e86a-4f98-9f3f-f31cc21621c7
STATUSBadRequest
PROVISIONING STATEFailed
TIMESTAMP4/28/2016, 10:12:57 AM
DURATIONPT2.0055957S
TYPEMicrosoft.ClassicStorage/StorageAccounts
RESOURCE ID/subscriptions/b2385f44-XXXX-4ff1-XXXX-
f09cbed8a333/resourceGroups/vmstorage/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/Storage
Accounts/appsrv

STATUSMESSAGE{
  "error": {
    "code": "StorageAccountOperationFailed",
    "message": "Unable to create storage account 'appsrv': 'The location constraint is not valid'."
  }
}
RESOURCEappsrv
```

I have been searching online for a while with no real answers as to how to resolve this. Am I missing a step? could it be because I just signed up and it is using the Free trial subscription? Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a restriction of the free Azure account - try changing your availability zone to us north.

> The location constraint is not valid

Comment: While possible, this isn't always the case. I added another answer for the other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Blob storage accounts are region locked, just like nearly everything in Azure.

There is a comprehensive and up to date [list maintained by microsoft](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/#services).
In your case, you want to look at the Blob Storage Accounts tab.

There are also ways to check using [powershell or other means.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-manager-supported-services/)

```
((Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web).ResourceTypes | Where-Object ResourceTypeName -eq sites).Locations
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you both! I got this from MS Tech support - makes no sense why i cannot create a storage account on a system in my own region, but whatever - no big deal.

"Hello Erick,

Thank you for your swift response.

I regret to inform you that both the regions (East US and East US 2) that you are trying to deploy are not enabled on your subscription hence it is not letting you create the storage account. The list of regions already available for your subscription are :

1. South Central US
2. Central US
3. North Europe
4. West Europe
5. Southeast Asia
6. Japan West
7. Japan East

If you like to deploy in any of these regions there should not be any error. However, if you like to deploy in East US / East US 2 we will need to place a request with Capacity Planning Team to enable these region for your subscription. I would request you to please advise if you want to deploy in any of the existing region or would you like to place a request with the Capacity Planning Team to enable East US and East US 2 region for your subscription."